# Reset list option-value when changing showon value

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I am currently writing a module with many backend settings, some of these use the "showon" attribute.

For example: I have two fields of type "list". In the second one, the options are evaluated with the "showon" of the first list.

```
    <field  name="fieldCat" 
            type="list" 
            default="0" 
            required="" 
            label="Category:" 
            description="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    </field>
    
    <field  name="fieldItem" 
            type="list" 
            default="0" 
            required="" 
            label="Item:" 
            description="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1" showon="fieldCat:1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2" showon="fieldCat:2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </field>
```

If I set the first list to Category 1, Item 1 is displayed and can be selected.

But if I now select Category 2, Item 1 remains in the second list.
Please see the picture:

[image]

Is it possible to reset the value of the second list (fieldItem) to default when changing the "higher-level" list (fieldCat)? Is this only possible with a custom field?

My currently soulution is, that I have separate subordinate lists (fieldItem1, fieldItem2) for each fieldCat value.

Comment: No, ‘`showon`’ is not for changing field values, so either you create a custom field solution on that or you use your already created solution.

Comment: Earlier I had a long write-up on how to create dynamically changing custom list/selection fields using Ajax. Maybe it can help you on the subject: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28763/how-to-dynamically-reload-admin-form-fields-in-joomla/28779#28779

Comment: Thanks for the answers Zollie and for the massive tutorial at [How to dynamically reload admin-form-fields in Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28763/how-to-dynamically-reload-admin-form-fields-in-joomla/28779#28779). Correct me if i am wrong, but i cant create a "models" folder for standalone modules right? Where I need to create the code for the custom fields?

Comment: @r4id - theoretically you can add models to a module too (and you can access DB Tables from a module directly without a model), but if you basically will not have too many values for the Form fields then you can just get the list/selection field values from an object or array coded in your custom Form field directly or in your module’s Helper file, you can also create fields folder within a module if you need that, so there are many ways to reformulate these codes of course. In a module you can also use Joomla base Classes which can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your own custom JS for this.

Here is an example for your given XML.

```
(function($) {
    var catFieldName = 'fieldCat';
    var itemFieldName = 'fieldItem';
    
    var showHideFieldOptions = function() {
        var selectedCategory = $('select[name="jform[params][' + catFieldName + ']"]').val(),
            $itemField = $('select[name="jform[params][' + itemFieldName + ']"]');
        
        $itemField.find('option[value="1"], option[value="2"]').attr('disabled', true);
        
        if (selectedCategory == 1) {
            $itemField.find('option[value="1"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else if (selectedCategory == 2) {
            $itemField.find('option[value="2"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        
        $itemField.trigger('liszt:updated');
    }
    
    $(function() {
        showHideFieldOptions();
        
        $('select[name="jform[params][' + catFieldName + ']"]').on('change', function() {
            showHideFieldOptions();
        });
    });
    
})(jQuery);
```

It will be better if you set the item field as required (required="true").

Comment: Yes, this is also a good and the simplest approach for solving this.

Comment: How about passing multiple selectors to `find()` when disabling? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11758129/2943403  Also, why not pass `selectedCategory` into `find()` when removing the attr, so that you don't need `if` and `else if`?  PHPStorm would probably complain to me if I wrote `$('select[name="jform[params][' + itemFieldName + ']"]')` 5 times instead declaring a re-usable variable.  https://jsfiddle.net/rkhm6ywa/

Comment: Yes, you can adjust the script based on actual usage. I have slightly edited the codes to minimise repetition.